# java synchronize database queries on application level

Tags: java, sql-server, database, oracle, concurrency

i need to perform db queries(SELECT, INSERT) on one table in multi-threaded application(non-distributed). Here is a scenario:

1. DB SELECT data
2. calculate data
3. DB INSERT new data according calculation

Each row must be unique so threads must perform this scenario one by one. Solution has to work on various DB servers(Oracle, MSSQL, Postgres)

I've got 2 approaches so far. 
One is on db level. I'm using lock on table(ORACLE) or on rows(MSSQL). It works just fine but there is some boilerplate code for each db i dont like.

MSSQL: SELECT data ... with (xlock,ROWLOCK)
ORACLE:lock table TBL1 in exclusive mode ... SELECT data...

2nd approach is on application level, Where i've got

```
    private static Object lock = new Object();
    void execute()
    {
     synchronized(lock){
       //perform DB SELECT data
        calculate(data);// eg.: data++;
       //perform DB INSERT data
     }
    }
```

It just work but i want to know if this 2nd approach is fair/correct enough?

Comment: Why do the DB query and calculation phases need to be synchronized? Is the data used for the calculation in the same table as the inserted row -- can you elaborate?

Comment: Let's say for sake of simplicity i want to generate sequence of number 1,2,3,4...etc but i dont want to use auto-increment feature. So each thread needs to read last (let's say max number) ,increment by 1  and insert new row with this number. ...Yes data for the calculation is in the same table as the inserted row.

Comment: If your solution has to support three different RDBMS, then the safest solution is probably to synchronize the data access on the application level. This might cause a huge performance hit (if you have many concurrent users) however, because essentially you're only allowing one user to update the table at a time and the locking time will include the latency between your app server and the DB.

Comment: May be this is the case for optimistic lock. Something like `UPDATE table1 SET data = data + 1 WHERE date = :previousValue`? Then you can look at the rows updated and spin on this update. This approach can be acceptable in some cases, eg. short transactions and simple calculations.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to work fine. I mean, it's hard too say if it's fast than database by just lookin at it. You should run some benchmarks! In my opinion, you should use database approach if other applications need to run this same code, on multi-application level, the synchronize way will not work.